# How to get rid of " error: SPAWN ls ENONET on Windows "?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, spawn

[I don't know why this error occurred "error: SPAWN ls ENONET"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0AYC.png)

Comment: well.... there is simply no 'ls' command in windows, right? so you can do something to windows (to recognize ls command) or to your program to detect/take parameter about OS type and spawn a different process, like "dir"

Comment: @VladimirM can you tell me how to do something with windows to take such commands?

Comment: it all depends on what exactly you want. one way is to google for "ls for Windows 10" and find a link to MS shop with free ls utility for windows. Though, when you post a question on stackOverflow it is generally expected that you have spent some of your own time researching the problem. As a new user you might have not known that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to use `ls` command, which does not exist on Windows, that is why you see the error.

What I would suggest you is to rely on `fs` module if you just want to list the content of the current directory. In general, you should avoid running CLI utilities if there is a native API that is available to you.

You can use [fs.readDir](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readdir-method/) function to replace `ls`.